# Set CSS property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I've created the following...

```
var menu = document.createElement('select');
```

How would I now set CSS attributes e.g `width: 100px`?

Answer (score 331, accepted):

Use [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style):

```
var element = document.createElement('select');
element.style.width = "100px";
```

Comment: What about for the unofficial ones like `-webkit-background-size`? Is there a way to set these with plain js or do we have to use jQuery?

Comment: @Luke obj.style["-webkit-background-size"] = "400px"

Comment: This actually styles the element in the element and not in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 71):

Just set the `style`:

```
var menu = document.createElement("select");
menu.style.width = "100px";
```

Or if you like, you can use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$(menu).css("width", "100px");
```

Comment: @Sime - My quotes aren't inconsistent. I always use double quotes for JS as that's the standard at work. Anyway, the first line had single quotes as I copied it from the OPs question. Corrected now anyway.

Comment: Well, they're OK now, but they were inconsistent at the time of my comment `:)`

Comment: @Sime - I did acknoledge that: *"Anyway, the first line had single quotes as I copied it from the OPs question. Corrected now anyway."*

Answer (score 49):

For most styles do this:

```
var obj = document.createElement('select');
obj.style.width= "100px";
```

For styles that have hyphens in the name do this instead:

```
var obj = document.createElement('select');
obj.style["-webkit-background-size"] = "100px"
```

Answer (score 39):

**Just for people who want to do the same thing in 2023**

You can assign a CSS custom property to your element (through CSS or JS) and change it:

**Assigment through CSS:**

```
element {
  --element-width: 300px;

  width: var(--element-width, 100%);
}
```

**Assignment through JS**

```
ELEMENT.style.setProperty('--element-width', NEW_VALUE);
```

**Get property value through JS**

```
ELEMENT.style.getPropertyValue('--element-width');
```

Here useful links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/removeProperty

Answer (score 20):

That's actually quite simple with vanilla JavaScript:

```
menu.style.width = "100px";
```

Answer (score 18):

All of the answers tell you correctly how to do what you asked but I would advise using JavaScript to set a class on the element and style it by using CSS.  That way you are keeping the correct separation between behaviour and style.

Imagine if you got a designer in to re-style the site... they should be able to work purely in CSS without having to work with your JavaScript.

In prototype I would do:

```
$(newElement).addClassName('blah')
```

Comment: +1 from me - much easier / cleaner to keep all your CSS separate.

Comment: jQuery version of this for reference... `$(selector).addClass('blah')`

Comment: Vanilla version: `newElement.classList.add('blah')`

Answer (score 11):

When debugging, I like to be able to add a bunch of css attributes in one line:

```
menu.style.cssText = 'width: 100px';
```

Getting used to this style you can add a bunch of css in one line like so:

```
menu.style.cssText = 'width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #afafaf';
```

Answer (score 7):

if you want to add a global property, you can use:

```
    var styleEl = document.createElement('style'), styleSheet;
            document.head.appendChild(styleEl);
            styleSheet = styleEl.sheet;
            styleSheet.insertRule(".modal { position:absolute; bottom:auto; }", 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<h1>Silence and Smile</h1>
<input  type="button"  value="Show Red"   onclick="document.getElementById('h1').style.color='Red'"/>
<input  type="button"  value="Show Green" onclick="document.getElementById('h1').style.color='Green'"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

This works well with most CSS properties if there are no hyphens in them.

```
var element = document.createElement('select');
element.style.width = "100px";
```

For properties with hyphens in them like `max-width`, you should convert the `sausage-case` to `camelCase`

```
var element = document.createElement('select');
element.style.maxWidth = "100px";
```

Comment: "sausage-case" is nice but I like "kebab-case" better :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<body>
  <h1 id="h1">Silence and Smile</h1><br />
  <h3 id="h3">Silence and Smile</h3>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("h1").style.color = "Red";
    document.getElementById("h1").style.background = "Green";
    document.getElementById("h3").style.fontSize = "larger" ; 
    document.getElementById("h3").style.fontFamily = "Arial";
  </script>
</body>
```