# How to define changing css property based on incrementing class names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, automation, classname

I've looked around and haven't seen this question answered before, so please forgive me if I'm mistaken.

What I have is a text string given by a user that can basically be anything. I split the string by newline characters, `"\n"`, so I differentiate between ideas in the text. I want to put each idea into a `<span>`, and have each span be spaced from the left side of the screen using `left: number-of px`. The problem I am running into is that I want the spacing to be dependent on the number of underscores starting out each idea. So if one idea is `"_Blah blah"`, the css should be `left: 5px`, and if the idea is `"__Blah blah"`, the css should be `left: 10px`.

Right now my code picks out the number of underscores at the beginning of each idea and creates a className in the span that the idea will be put into.

I know this is doable by having lots of css properties like this:

```
.lvl1-1 {
    left: 0px;
}
.lvl1-2 {
    left: 5px;
}
.lvl1-3 {
    left: 10px;
}
... and so on
```

But because the text is unknown, and there may be infinite levels and sub-levels, I would appreciate it if I could have some css field or something that will auto-increment the left property depending on the className. Is this possible? Thanks for any help!

Here's a demo that may be useful: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q24G7/)

Comment: You could only use 3 classes: .lvl-1: 5px, lvl-2: 10px and lvl-3: 15px. An example here: http://jsfiddle.net/q24G7/2/

Comment: @srekoble, I could have many more than 3 sub-levels. But your simplification is helpful

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian - Do you mean right when I create each element I could do [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195303/set-css-attribute-in-javascript)?

Comment: Do you really have to use a class? Why not change the style of the element directly?

Comment: @Fabricio for this example, no. But later I will need to access these elements by class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using comments from @LowerClassOverflowian, @srekoble and @AndreiVolgin, I came up with this solution:

```
var newDiv = $('<div></div>')
    .text(lines[i])
    .css({
        'margin-left':(underscoreCount * 5) + 'px'
    });
$('#div-text').append(newDiv);
```

Where `underscoreCount` is the number of underscores in each idea, `lines[i]` is the idea being added, and `div-text` is the id of the div containing the added divs.

Comment: Or use <div> instead of <span> and simply set margin-left

Comment: @AndreiVolgin - and therefore not need `position:relative`?

Comment: And you don't need a CSS class for a span if you set position in code.

Comment: Div is a block element. You should not use span for what you try to accomplish.