# How to add variable color to span text

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have a span with some text that changes every time the user clics a button. I need the color of it to change with every clic (I have the colors in an array like this: var colorArray = ["red","blue","red","red","green","blue","green","red"])

The array is not fixed as I read it from DB.

Any idea on how to do this via javascript (it's for a phonegap project)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195303/set-css-attribute-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you click on the button you can take the first element of your array and put it at the end of it, so it's a loop.

After with jQuery [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function you can put the first color of the array to your `span`.

Code should look like this :

```
var colorArray = ["red","blue","green"];
$('button').click(function(){
    $('span').css({"color":colorArray[0]});
    colorArray.push(colorArray.shift());
});
```

**[See this Fiddle for more details](http://jsfiddle.net/TXv7u/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and the css() function. Please have a look at the documentation for this function at http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2 (there are also some examples in the end of the site). In the end you will have something like this:

```
$("span#id").css("color", target_color);
```

Instead of `span#id` you have to use the CSS selector for the target `<span>` element and `target_color` has to be the color of your array, you want to use.

Comment: The code would be along these lines: `$('span').css("color", colorArray[i])`

Answer (score 1):

**If you want pure js Here is the js code:**

```
<script>
  var color = {
    currentColor: 0,
    colorArray: ["red","blue","red","red","green","blue","green","red","orange"],
    changeColor: function(){
      document.getElementById('span1').style.color = color.colorArray[color.currentColor];
      if (color.currentColor < color.colorArray.length-1){
        color.currentColor++;
      }else{
        color.currentColor = 0;
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

**Here ir your html:**

```
<input type="button" value="change color" onclick="color.changeColor()">

<span id="span1"></span>
```