# Change Font by Option Dropdown Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

I'm trying to change the font of a div with an option selector.

so i have the div with the text "hello folks"
and i want to change the font-family either font1 or font2 (or font3)

But i can't imagine a right way and i'm getting really confused whether to define styles by css classes or by javascript referenc. 
could anybody help me??

```
 <div id="output-text">
  hello folks 
</div

  <label for="input-font">
Font
</label>
<br>
<select id="input-font" class="input"  onchange="changeFont (this);" size="2">

  <option selected ="selected"/>
  Helvetica

  <option />
  Arial

</select>
<br>
```

a simple change font script would be this, but i cant bring them together with that options dropdown

```
function changeFont(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('input-font').value;
    document.getElementById('output_font').innerHTML = userInput;

}
```

but i guess i'm totally wrong here

Comment: You didn't post your `changeFont` function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195303/set-css-attribute-in-javascript

Comment: Add the function you've written (`changeFont()`). Also, on a side note, you may want to test with something other than helvetica and arial as your options--you may not see much difference.

Comment: You have issues in your HTML formatting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's your example cleaned up and working.

```
<div id="output-text">
  hello folks 
</div>

<select id="input-font" class="input"  onchange="changeFont (this);">
      <option value="Times New Roman" selected ="selected">Times New Roman</option>
      <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
var changeFont = function(font){
  console.log(font.value)
    document.getElementById("output-text").style.fontFamily = font.value;
}
```

Now you can add as many fonts in the dropdown list in the HTML and it will work.. 
Working example here:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9c4jsqf9/2/)

Answer (score 2):

As you haven't posted the `changefont()` function I can't see what have you tried in your code. As in your question:

```
Change Font by Option Dropdown Javascript
```

You can just create an element with an and and change its font size like

```
    document.getElementById("theid").style.fontFamily = "Arial";
```

You can use `selectedIndex` property to fetch the selected value from dropdown.

More info about selecting value from a dropdown is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript).

Comment: I think @user2607713 also wants to know how to get the "Arial" part - that is, how to use the selected item from the drop-down list.

Comment: i can undestand the principle of changing the font like <script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myP").style.fontFamily = "Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif";
}
</script>


yes… but u don't get how to change it with more options like there's a dropdown list: -arial, -comic sans, -……… (sorry i'm new to it so i'm just totally confused at the moment how count 1+1 together…

Comment: you do-not need to use selected index. Solution is much simpler, check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This may help

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeFont(str){
        document.getElementById("output-text").setAttribute("style", "font-family:"+str+";");
    }
    </script>
    <div id="output-text">
      hello folks 
    </div>

    <label for="input-font">
    Font
    </label>
    <br>
    <select id="input-font" class="input"  onchange="changeFont(this.value);">
      <option value="Georgia" selected ="selected">Georgia</option>
      <option value="Arial" >Arial</option>
    </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to restructure your select a bit (use `value=""` in the `<option>` tags to pass font names to javascript -- also your `<option>` tags needs a bit of work to be propperly formatted HTML) and then define the changeFont() function. [**JSFIDDLE DEOM**](http://jsfiddle.net/p0t6Lvuu/)

```
<select id="input-font" class="input"  onchange="changeFont()" size="2">
  <option selected ="selected" value="Helvetica">Helvetica</option>
  <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
  <option value="Times">Times</option>
</select>

function changeFont() {
    var myselect = document.getElementById("input-font");   //get the input element and store in variable 'myselect'
    var font = myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value;   //store the value="" of the selected element in variable 'font'
    document.getElementById("output-text").style.fontFamily = font;   //set 'output-text' element's font-family style to value in 'font' variable
}
```

alternative changeFont() function with backup font

```
function changeFont() {
    var myselect = document.getElementById("input-font");  
    var font = myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value;
    font = font + ", sans-serif";  //gives the font variable a backup font in-case the system lacks the selected font
    document.getElementById("output-text").style.fontFamily = font;   
}
```