# My css border color not applying using Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, border-color

I am learning jquery and am trying to use css in jquery by applying border color to blue but it is not applying. I have searched and looked a lot of tutorials but I am unable to apply the blue color. The website is very basic and as I am trying to understand the concept steadily.

There is no error showing but the when I run the program, the border around the image is completely blank I tried changing the sizes but still nothing changed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").click(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('p').click(function() {
        $('img').css("border", "20px solid blue");
      });
    });

  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
  /* Center the nav bar */
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  color: burlywood;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  /* Display list items inline */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" -->
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact us">contact us</a></li>
      <li><a href="home">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="news">news</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  </div>
  <p>this is a paragraph</p>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300">
  <p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp">w3schools</a></p>
  <p>hello this is random text.</p>
  <input type="text" id="text"><br><br>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of jQuery?

Comment: Make sure you're using a good editor. You have HTML that's invalid for several reasons. You have an extra closing div tag, and you have content outside the head and body elements. A good editor (and proper formatting) will make those problems apparent.

Comment: Did you look at your code and ask yourself what it does? It doesn't make much sense to duplicate functions like that.

Comment: The border color is updated when you double click on a paragraph

Comment: Well, click _twice_.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need those double `$(document).ready(` and `.click(` functions.

Removing those give the following demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("p").click(function () {
      $('img').css("border", "20px solid blue");    
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("p").click(function () {
      $('img').css("border", "20px solid blue");    
  });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

nav {
    text-align: center; /* Center the nav bar */
}

nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    color: burlywood;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav li {
    display: inline; /* Display list items inline */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact us">contact us</a></li>
        <li><a href="home">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news">news</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
    <p>this is a paragraph</p>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300">
    <p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp">w3schools</a></p>
    <p>hello this is random text.</p>
    <input type="text" id="text"><br><br>
```

---

Keep in mind that you *[You might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)*, using native Javascript, it will look like:

```js
[ ...document.querySelectorAll('p') ].forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const image = document.querySelector('img');
        image.style.border = '20px solid blue';
    });
})
```

Adding that to the demo gives:

```js
[ ...document.querySelectorAll('p') ].forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const image = document.querySelector('img');
        image.style.border = '20px solid blue';
    });
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

nav {
    text-align: center; /* Center the nav bar */
}

nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    color: burlywood;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav li {
    display: inline; /* Display list items inline */
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact us">contact us</a></li>
        <li><a href="home">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news">news</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
    <p>this is a paragraph</p>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300">
    <p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp">w3schools</a></p>
    <p>hello this is random text.</p>
    <input type="text" id="text"><br><br>
```

- [How to loop through selected elements with document.querySelectorAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330086/how-to-loop-through-selected-elements-with-document-queryselectorall)
- [Set CSS property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195303/set-css-property-in-javascript)

Comment: I would use, `$("p").on('click', function() {` instead.

Comment: Agree, I'd not even use jQuery at all ;) Didn't want to change OP's code that much, so I'll keep it like that. The JS solution is preferred anyway.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, your suggestion doesn't mean much without some supporting reasoning.

Comment: @isherwood It's better for event delegation.

Comment: I know that. Not everyone who reads your comment does. Bald assertions are not useful.